# loopback angular Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: mysql, angularjs, loopbackjs

I am very new to loopback.  am trying to use the angular SDK.

i've got an instance of the front-end running on localhost:3000.  i have an instance of the server on http://0.0.0.0:3000/.

i've set the base url using `LoopBackResourceProvider.setUrlBase('http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/');`.

using the built-in User model...

```
User.getCurrent(() => {
    console.log(1);
});
```

throws... `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`.

i can use the loopback explorer to CRUD into the user table so the db connection is working.

inspecting any XHR's from the app, shows that no requests are being made to the server.

Comment: Thats returning a promise probably, so do `User.getCurrent().then(function (u) {console.log(u)})`

Comment: @reptilicus with your edit, its now throwing `User.getCurrent(...).then is not a function`.  the docs for `getCurrent` shows that param1 is the success callback and param2 is the error.

Comment: Then do `User.getCurrent(function (resp) {console.log(resp)})`